# Root broadcast can by-pass an Android app custom permission?

Tags: android, security, broadcastreceiver, root, broadcast

I'm developping two apps (on Android 4.2.2), app A that contains a "private" area and app B that can open the private area with an Intent.
I have used a custom Permission with protectionLevel="signature" to be sure the broadcast will be receive only if A and B are built with the same keystore, and it works well.

After this, I have made some tests, and finally find a way to "bypass" the Permission by using:

`su -c am broadcast ...` from an app that did not define the custom permission

So it means that if someone install the application A on a rooted device, he could send a broadcast message to my app and access the "private" area...

From my point of view, I'm not sure if it's a security breach or the expected behaviour.
I have found no documentation about this...
Do I really need to add a password in extras or something like that to be sure this access is protected?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got set the permission attribute in yuor manifest in the section of your receiver?

Comment: Yes, and it works as expected: if app B tries to send a message without declaring the exact same permission, it doesn't work; and if it declares the permission, it works.